# 16.04 amdgpu-pro, no hdmi sound

Tags: 16.04, sound, hdmi, amd-graphics

16.04, AMD Radeon 7700

here's what i've tried:

disabling onboard sound in bios.
editing grub: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.audio=1"`, running `update-grub` and rebooting

opening pavucontrol shows the card, but says it's unplugged. there is no option for an HDMI selection that is "plugged in"

aplay -l lists the following:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

pactl list sinks returns:

```
Sink #0
    State: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo
    Description: Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7700/7800 Series] Digital Stereo (HDMI)
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 6
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 95020 / 145% / 9.68 dB,   front-right: 95020 / 145% / 9.68 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    Monitor Source: alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo.monitor
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY SET_FORMATS
```

I don't know what else to try, nothing seems to be working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You didn't list your card model number. AMD cards are supposed to have lots of new support built into Kernel 4.9.0 which came out last Sunday. Might be worth a try. http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.9/

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Radeon HD 7700, I've just discovered that running `pactl list sinks` shows sink#0 in state: suspended.

Comment: Well the state should say "RUNNING". You can try: `sudo -u YOUR_USER_NAME -E pacmd set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-stereo` but that's the limit to my knowledge :(

Comment: Also noticed your volume is set at 145% and I've never had mine above 100%. Probably doesn't matter but just wanted to point it out...

Answer (score 2):

... I also regularly merge the code base with the latest kernel patches here: https://github.com/M-Bab/linux-kernel-amdgpu . And if you are a lazy and trustingly person you can also try the compiled kernel binaries from https://github.com/M-Bab/linux-kernel-amdgpu-binaries . On the last page you get also some additional information about the whole issue. I would generally not recommend to install compiled binaries from a random guy on the internet - the only reason I make an exception here is because I am the random guy.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options to get HDMI audio working since the change to amdgpu:

1. Install the proprietary amdgpu-pro driver:
   http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.asp
2. Use a kernel with DAL/DC enabled combined with the open source amdgpu driver. The original source code is amd-staging-4.9 from https://cgit.freedesktop.org/~agd5f/linux/log/?h=amd-staging-4.9 ...

Comment: would you kindly post the relevant parts from the links, since links can die?

Comment: Yeah right. Linux amdgpu-pro driver can be found here: http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/linux